# How To Reference TableView Section Label? Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

EDIT: Need to add more code as what I had before was all wrong and irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Save section titles in an array, say, `var sectionTitles: [String]`.

```swift
var sectionTitles: [String]
```

Set button's tag property to you section index in `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

```swift
button.tag = section
```

Get section index by using button's tag property in `addItem` method.

```swift
let sectionIndex = button.tag;
```

Then you can get your section title.

```swift
moreDetail.getWorkoutTitle = self.sectionTitles[sectionIndex]
```

Comment: Hi Zhuang, The issue i have now after implementing this is that the index is out of range - when implementing section title